# How would I get color output from MC/Bukkit server to be displayed in custom server wrapper?

Tags: c#, minecraft, bukkit, system.diagnostics

I'm working on a console-based [wrapper for a Minecraft server](https://github.com/bmlzootown/MC-Wrapper) written in C#, and am currently using System.Diagnostics.Process to start the server and redirect input/output (which works as intended).

The downside is that I can't seem to get color output working. I'm sure jline/jansi perform some sort of environment check (as `"2018-07-22 19:39:56,223 main WARN Disabling terminal, you're running in an unsupported environment"` would indicate), but I'm not sure as to how to go about convincing it otherwise/faking an actual supported environment, or if such is even possible.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: (I'm not familiar with Minecraft's command-line code, but as it's a Java application does it use `stdin`/`stdout` in a normal Windows Console Host window (just like `cmd.exe`) or does it have a Java Swing/AWT/non-native console window?

Comment: Upvoter and OP perhaps need a refresher of [ask]

Comment: @Dai There is a GUI, but I believe running it via command `java -jar serverexe nogui` does the former (if I'm understanding correctly).


@MickyD Sorry about that -- I've updated the title to something that is hopefully more appropriate.

Comment: You are doing that for minecraft server or spigot etc?

Comment: @GotoFinal Bukkit/Spigot/Paper

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this colors would not be in minecraft format, but in ansi codes.
This setting can be overridden by system property:

```
            // This trick bypasses Maven Shade's clever rewriting of our getProperty call when using String literals
            String jline_UnsupportedTerminal = new String(new char[] {'j','l','i','n','e','.','U','n','s','u','p','p','o','r','t','e','d','T','e','r','m','i','n','a','l'});
            String jline_terminal = new String(new char[] {'j','l','i','n','e','.','t','e','r','m','i','n','a','l'});

            useJline = !(jline_UnsupportedTerminal).equals(System.getProperty(jline_terminal));

            if (options.has("nojline")) {
                System.setProperty("user.language", "en");
                useJline = false;
            }

            if (useJline) {
                AnsiConsole.systemInstall();
            } else {
                // This ensures the terminal literal will always match the jline implementation
                System.setProperty(jline.TerminalFactory.JLINE_TERMINAL, jline.UnsupportedTerminal.class.getName());
            }


            if (options.has("noconsole")) {
                useConsole = false;
            }
```

https://github.com/TacoSpigot/CraftBukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/Main.java#L145-L166

So you need to set `jline.terminal` property to some valid value - in this case seems that it can be anything other than `jline.Unsupported` and non-null, and probably you will need to force library to emit colors:  https://github.com/fusesource/jansi/blob/master/jansi/src/main/java/org/fusesource/jansi/AnsiConsole.java
`boolean forceColored = Boolean.getBoolean("jansi.force");`
So change `jansi.force` property to true too.

Comment: I was under the impression that, since it uses System.getProperty(), setting the jvm option `-Djline.terminal=windows` would work, but it doesn't seem to have any effect (nor does setting jansi.force). Am I just completely missing something obvious?

Comment: @bmlzootown you can just debug that code as I already showed you where this is prepared

Comment: @bmlzootownbut but seems that spigot uses older version of that library, and it will just don't support that